# Validating one field in a class with class-validator

Tags: typescript, class-validator

Let's say I have this class based on the example in the docs (https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#usage)

```
import {MinLength, MaxLength, validate} from "class-validator";

export class Post {

    @IsString()
    body: strong;

    @IsString()
    title: string;

    //...many more fields

    public async validate(){
        validate(this, { forbidUnknownValues: true, validationError: { target: false } });
    }
}
```

I create an instance of this class and assign values to the fields.

```
const post = new Post()
post.body = 'body'
post.title = 'title'
// ... assign all the other fields
```

I want to validate `post`, skipping validation for all the fields except `title`. There doesn't seem to be a way to do this aside from assigning groups to all fields, which I don't want to do. Is there a way to just validate this single field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately, there is not a way to validate just a single field without assigning groups.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed [this](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/114#issuecomment-785748152) and it works for me.

A workaround way is that you only pass one field and validate with 'skipMissingProperties' option.

```
const exampleModel = new ExampleModel();
exampleModel.password = '123abc'

const errors = await validate(exampleModel, { skipMissingProperties: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over the validation errors and only act on the fields that match.

```js
async function validateField(obj, field) {
    try {
        await validateOrReject(obj);
    } catch (errors) {
        errors.forEach((err) => {
            if(field == err.property) {
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```